How do you log in to Sonatype Nexus Repository Manager?
My question is stupidly simple: how do you log in to Nexus Repository Manager at https://oss.sonatype.org/?

Longer explanation:
I'm trying to debug why ./gradlew publish fails with a 401 error:
Execution failed for task ':initializeSonatypeStagingRepository'.
> Failed to load staging profiles, server at https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/ responded with status code 401, body: 

I have the following in my build.gradle.kts
plugins {
    id("io.github.gradle-nexus.publish-plugin") version "2.0.0"
    id("maven-publish")
    id("signing")
}

nexusPublishing {
    repositories {
        sonatype {
            val baseUrl = "https://oss.sonatype.org"
            nexusUrl.set(URI("$baseUrl/service/local/"))
            snapshotRepositoryUrl.set(URI("$baseUrl/content/repositories/snapshots/"))
            username.set(System.getenv("SONATYPE_USER"))
            password.set(System.getenv("SONATYPE_PASSWORD"))
        }
    }
}

I figured the very first thing I should do is manually make sure my SONATYPE_USER and SONATYPE_PASSWORD actually work, so I head on over to https://oss.sonatype.org/ and click log in.
This is where it gets confusing to me: when I created a Sonatype account at https://central.sonatype.com/api/auth/login, I created it through GitHub. So, I do not actually have a "Sonatype username and password" per se. Alas, on https://oss.sonatype.org/ there is no option to sign in via GitHub, so I try using the user token I generated at https://central.sonatype.com/account, but it is rejected.
There's no option to create an account or reset a forgotten password, and when you fail to log in, the error message tells you to "Please login before attempting further requests." (?!) To add to the confusion, the error message also does not clearly differentiate between whether the username+password combination is incorrect, or if it is correct but the account lacks permissions.
Surprisingly, I couldn't find anything in their documentation explaining how to login here. And of course before coming here to StackOverflow, I tried contacting their support, but my ticket was immediately closed because I'm not a paying customer.
So, how exactly are you supposed to log in?


Sonatype has two different ways (systems) to publish an artefact. Each system has a different user database.

Publish the artefact using Browser Upload. This requires you to register at https://central.sonatype.com. I did this for the first time last year and was not able to publish mvn deploy like you do with gradle.

Until recently, there was a Jira (issues.sonatype.org) where you had to register. These credentials were what you needed to publish. You had to confirm your GroupId via a ticket. However, this was turned off earlier this year. You can log in to https://s01.oss.sonatype.org/ with this credentials.


Sonytype is currently reorganising its systems and processes.
At the moment I am not sure what the status is regarding the changeover and what the process is regarding the account including verification of the GroupID.
I received this email at the beginning of March. The best thing to do is to send an email to central-support@sonatype.com that you need an account for Maven Central and want to verify your GroupID. I recently had a request and got a quick response.

Greetings Maven Central Publisher,
We are reaching out to you because you are registered as a publisher
with Maven Central’s oss.sonatype.org or s01.oss.sonatype.org
services. Although there are no immediate changes to how you publish,
we want to inform you of a number of upcoming changes to your account.
Currently, you manage your account credentials through
issues.sonatype.org. On Tuesday the 12th of March, we are moving
account management to a temporary service located at
https://account.oss.sonatype.org/realms/central-ossrh/account/. This
should hopefully involve minimal disruption for our publishers. You
will still use the same username and password to log in to the OSSRH
instance, and should only need to interact with the new account
management service when you wish to change or reset your account
credentials.
Also, you will likely see information directed at new OSSRH publishers
registering via central.sonatype.com (documented here --
https://central.sonatype.org/register/legacy/). While this does not
impact you at the moment, you should be aware that we are moving
account management to a unified system across the Central Publishing
Portal and OSSRH. We will communicate again before that takes place,
to ensure that our users have a clear understanding of where and how
they will be able to manage their accounts.
You may also have been impacted by the retirement of
issues.sonatype.org which you previously used for signing up for new
namespaces and getting publishing support. We have transitioned to
using the same workflow system used for our paid products. To generate
a ticket, you can email central-support@sonatype.com. We acknowledge
that, in doing so, you have lost some of the self-service
functionality for requesting and being granted publisher access to new
namespaces. We are working on restoring that functionality on
central.sonatype.com. The migration to a unified account management
system we mentioned previously enables us to build integrations
between the two services later in the year, such as displaying a
user’s complete list  of registered namespaces and allowing
self-service migration to the Publisher Portal.
Thank you, The Central Team


I really appreciate you taking the time to post this response, but I haven't accepted it since it doesn't actually answer the question. I still have no clue how to sign in. As far as I can tell, there is no way to log in now, and we have to wait for Sonatype to finish their migration to their "unified system."

But it's there. You need to write an email in the meantime: "You may also have been impacted by the retirement of issues.sonatype.org which you previously used for signing up for new namespaces and getting publishing support. We have transitioned to using the same workflow system used for our paid products. To generate a ticket, you can email central-support@sonatype.com."
